# Insert com Bootstrap Switch

Tags: php

Estou tendo uma duvida no seguinte cenário, estou tentando inserir o status usando o plugin [Link do Plugin](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) Segue resumo do codigo que estou usando

```
$status = $_POST['status'];

$stmt->bindParam("status", $status);
$stmt->execute();

<input type="checkbox"  id="destacar"  name="destacar"  value="sim" checked>

<script type="text/javascript"> $("[destacar='sim']").bootstrapSwitch(); </script>
```

Minha duvida é o seguinte: Como faço para para que se no visual estiver off inserir NAO; e se estiver on inserir SIM ?

Comment: Off-topic: Seu selector `$("[destacar='sim']")` parece errado, acredito que o corretor seria `$("#destacar:checked")`, `destacar='sim'` iria procusar elementos como `<div destacar="sim"></div>` e não o atributo `value`.

Answer (score 0):

resolvi o problema é só pegar o post e defini-lo:

```
$destacar = (isset($_POST['destacar'])) ? 1 : 0;
$status = (isset($_POST['status'])) ? 1 : 0;
```